# How can I detect if my GHUB profile is in G-Shift mode within a LUA script?

Tags: logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a LUA script on my profile, but I only want it to execute when the profile is G-shifted.
Is there some GHUB Lua api for detecting that? I don't see anything in the G_series_Lua_API.pdf

i.e.
if (g-shifted)
doSomething
end

I tried searching around but could not find any information about this.

Comment: You can set a `MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED` handler on the mouse button used as G-Shift switch.  You can simply set a boolean flag inside the handler to read it later.

Comment: Ok, so no direct way to read that, but this will work so long as I don't manually G-Shift the profile (unfortunately what I have been doing). I was also considering making the DPI of each almost the same 799 vs 800 and reading that, but I have not tried to do that yet.

Comment: How can you manually G_Shift the profile?

Comment: When looking at the profile for my G600 there is a toggle under the view of the mouse that will flip it into/out of G-Shift. I've never actually used G-Shift like a shift button, I was using it like a second profile that easier to switch to.

Comment: BTW, you can assign "Profile Cycle" action to any mouse button.  So, you can switch profiles without opening GHub GUI.  Different profiles have different Lua scripts.  So, there is no problem to determine which profile you are currently in.